# JavaScript Syntax Uses Benefits

Tags: syntax

JavaScript
Code
Syntax

Detail information about JavaScript
How to use JavaScript
when to use this
what type of language is this?
how JavaScript different from html and CSS
what are its applications and advantages
Is this helpful in future?
What is the first step to learn JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is likely to be closed as it's very broad and seeking recommendations, and therefore likely to attract subjective answers. However if you want to learn about JavaScript, HTML and CSS, https://www.w3schools.com/ is probably a good place to start.